# Ruby on Rails - PayPal transaction URL with different currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'd like to build a PayPal transaction URL with EUR currency.

When I fire up this URL, paypal shows me the price with USD currency:

```
  def paypal_url(return_path)
    values = {
        business: "paypal@mystore.de",
        cmd: "_xclick",
        upload: 1,
        return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
        invoice: id,
        amount: product.price,
        item_name: product.name,
        item_number: product.id,
        quantity: '1',
        notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
    }
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

I found this in the docs:

```
  amount: {
    total: 1.1,
    currency: 'USD'
  }
```

But when I put that

```
  amount: {
    total: product.price,
    currency: 'EUR'
  }
```

into the URL, Paypal shows an error that I've passed a bad amount value.